# Creating raster with PatchStat values from SDMTools in R

Tags: r, merge, raster, spatstat

I have a raster file of land cover which I have reduced to contain just tree cover cells. I have used `clump` in the raster package to clump() together contiguous areas of forest. This gives all cells touching one another the same ID because they are part of the same patch.
I then want to figure out the PatchStat() for each clump, which I do by converting my clump raster to as.matrix. I tried to get the PatchStat() to do this to the raster but it would only work if it was in a matrix.

I now want to make a raster with the patch stat output, namely "perim.area.ratio". So each cell that corresponds to clump 1, will get the perim.area.ratio value that corresponds to clump 1. To do this I made a data.frame() from my clump raster that had: `lon, lat, layer(clumpID), cellID`.
I tried to merge my clump raster data.frame with the PatchStat output using **layer** and **patchID**. However, an error occurs:

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify valid column(s).

Any ideas how I could do this another way, or why these columns aren't valid? Code below.

```
clump <- raster(file.choose())
library(SDMTools)
clumpval <- rasterToPoints(clump)
clumpcell <- cellFromXY(clump, clumpval[, c('x', 'y')] )
clumpdf <- data.frame(clumpval, clumpcell)
ps.data <- PatchStat(as.matrix(clump))
merged.data.all <- merge(clumpdf, ps.data1, by=c("layer", "patchID"))
```

Comment: The help file (http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=SDMTools:PatchStat) says that: "a matrix of data with individual patches identified as with ConnCompLabel; The matrix can be a raster of class 'asc' (adehabitat package), 'RasterLayer' (raster package) or 'SpatialGridDataFrame' (sp package)". If you are working with RasterLayer (if you're using `raster` you probably are), you could avoid having to convert to matrix and back.

Comment: Hi @RomanLustirk, thanks for the reply. Yes I am working with a 'RasterLayer', when I check the properties of my raster it says it at the top. However, it does't work if I just put in the raster, I get an error message... Not sure why but couldn't figure that out either! Cheers, Adam

Comment: What is the error message? `r <- raster(ncols=12, nrows=12); r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))*0.6 ); rc <- clump(r); PatchStat(rc)` works for me.

Comment: G'day @jbaums this is the error i get:
Error in if (m[ii] == 0) minp[ii] = 4 * n[ii] : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: I can't reproduce your 'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed' error, but have updated my solution below to explain the reason for your primary problem.

Answer (score 2):

The way you've coded it, the `merge` function is expecting both data frames to have both a 'layer' field *and* a 'patchID' column, whereas in fact you intend to map the layer column of clumpdf to the patchID column of ps.data. You need to use `by.x` and `by.y` arguments.

The correct call would be:

```
merged.data.all <- merge(clumpdf, ps.data, by.x='layer', by.y="patchID")
```

However, there's another simple way to assign cells their clump's `perim.area.ratio`:

```
library(raster)
library(SDMTools)

# create a random raster
r <- raster(ncols=200, nrows=200)
r[] <- rbinom(ncell(r), 1, 0.5)

# clump it
rc <- clump(r)

# get patch stats
p <- PatchStat(rc)

# Replace each non-NA value of rc with the corresponding clump perim.area.ratio.
not.na <- Which(!is.na(rc), cells=TRUE)
rc[not.na] <- sapply(rc[not.na], function(x) {
  p[p$patchID==x, 'perim.area.ratio']
})
```

To break it down for you (in case you're not particularly familiar with `apply` functions), this last bit firstly identifies the cell indices of all cells with non-NA values, and assigns this vector to the object `not.na`. The `sapply` function then assigns each value of `not.na` in turn to `x`, and performs the stuff between the curly braces (which in this case just returns the `perim.area.ratio` value found in the row of `p` that has `patchID` equal to `x`). The `sapply` function returns a vector of these `perim.area.ratio` values, which is then assigned to the non-NA cells of `rc`. In essence, it's a find & replace operation, where patch numbers are replaced by their corresponding `perim.area.ratios`.

I should mention that this may not work if you have a very large grid.